# Why the need for () when importing services in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am studying angular 2 and have found this statement disturbing.

> Don't forget the parentheses! Neglecting them leads to an error that's
>   difficult to diagnose.

While reading [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html)

Why is there a parenteses there what is it's function? Why have it there in the first place if it causes "hard to throubleshoot" problems?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These parens are not related to imports but to decorators

```
@Injectable() // correct
export class MyService {...}
```

vs

```
@Injectable // wrong
export class MyService {...}
```

because a function reference is quite different from a function invocation.

Answer (score 2):

I forget these parens all the time, actually!

It's the parentheses after the *decorator* that they're warning you about. This is because a decorator is a function that runs on the class -- it can take arguments (for example, we usually give the `@Component` decorator an object of options, like `template` and `selector`).

For example:

```
@Input teacherName: string;
```

vs.

```
@Input() teacherName: string;
```

gets me in trouble all of the time. And the error message is not helpful! Perhaps this is a difficult bug to catch at the compilation step?

In your case, it's remembering the parentheses after the `Injectable` decorator:

```
@Injectable() export class myService
```

vs.

```
@Injectable export class myService
```

To put this in perspective, another bad habit I have regarding parentheses is:

```
export class Teacher() {
```

vs.

```
export class Teacher {
```

Here, I need to make sure that I *don't* put parens before the class. Very similar, and leads to very confusing error messages!